# Dynamically producing content type fields from a drop down menu

Tags: views, rules

I have a content type called *payment schedule* that has a *payment amount* and *payment date*.

When creating a payment schedule, it should say something like *Number of payments* to make and let me choose a value (the number of payments) from a drop down menu. For example, I could choose 1, 2, 12, 16, right up to 24.

Based on the number  it should generate an *amount* box and a *payment date* box. This means, if I choose 24 it gives me 24 x 2 boxes - one for the amount and one for the date. If I choose 6 - it would give me 12 - 6 for the amount and 6 for the payment date.

What's the best way to go about this? if there's a module that can do this or writing my own or looking at something like rules or ajax, or can it be done in views

Comment: Rules & Views aren't really applicable to what you're looking for. You're looking for some type of custom entity with custom functionality.

Comment: I think you need to try [conditional field state](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_conditional_state) or [conditional field](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) to achieve this.